# Spyder IDE: Need to press 'run script' twice to successfully execute Python script

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder

I'm currently working on an image processing script in Python (Spyder IDE, Python 3.5, Anaconda 4.0.0). When I first open the IDE, I only have to press 'run script' once for the script to execute. But after that, I have to press 'run script' twice, sometimes even three times, for it to execute. Searching around the internet, it seems that the issue has to do with using `matplotlib` and `pyplot`. It's mainly an issue because I will spend 5 minutes per test just getting my script to execute. My code is included below. I decided to ask about the issue here to see if anyone might have a suggestion or idea to get my script to execute on the first press.

EDIT: Whenever I restart my kernel (start a new console), I'm able to get the script run on the first press.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
from skimage import data, img_as_float 
from skimage.filters import gaussian 
from skimage.segmentation import active_contour 
from skimage import io 

from skimage import exposure 

import scipy 
scipy_version = list(map(int, scipy.__version__.split('.')))
new_scipy = scipy_version[0] > 0 or \
            (scipy_version[0] == 0 and scipy_version[1] >= 14)

'''
img = data.astronaut()
img = rgb2gray(img)
'''


openLocation = "file location here"

img = io.imread(openLocation)
#img = rgb2gray(img)



s = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 600)
x = 400 + 300*np.cos(s)
y = 550 + 280*np.sin(s)
init = np.array([x, y]).T

if not new_scipy:
    print('You are using an old version of scipy. '
          'Active contours is implemented for scipy versions '
          '0.14.0 and above.')



if new_scipy:
    snake = active_contour(img, init, alpha=0.01, beta=0.01, w_line = 5, w_edge = 0, gamma=0.01, bc = 'periodic')

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7, 7))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    plt.gray()
    ax.imshow(img)
    ax.plot(init[:, 0], init[:, 1], '--r', lw=3)
    ax.plot(snake[:, 0], snake[:, 1], '-b', lw=3)
    ax.set_xticks([]), ax.set_yticks([])
    ax.axis([0, img.shape[1], img.shape[0], 0])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is related to [this](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/1831) its a bug in `spyder`.It provides a partial solution so far is to use a different Matplotlib backend. You can change it in:

```
Preferences > Console > External modules > Matplotlib
```

from the default (Qt4Agg) to TkAgg (the only other available on Windows).

One more thing you can try is updating `spyder` and then try running your script.

Comment: I changed the Matplotlib backend, but I still have to press run twice. HOWEVER, it seems that the script now executes immediately after pressing run the second time.

Comment: this is a partial solution as described on github, I think it will be fixed in next release.